# How to extend both ReceiverAdapter and java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject

Tags: java, server, rmi, jgroups

I'm currently working on an auctioning system where a client connects to a front end using Java RMI and then the front end connects to one server also using Java RMI. The front end also connects to the cluster of servers using `JGroups` and manages the data on the servers ensuring all servers have the same data stored on them by passing messages to them. However, my servers all need to extend `ReceiverAdapter` so they can receive messages, as well as extending `java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject` when using RMI with the front end. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending `UnicastRemoteObject`, call its static method on your object:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(object, port);
```

(or the 4-argument overloading method).

The [`UnicastRemoteObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html)'s API lists 6 ways to export an object. 3 involve subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and the other 3 involve calling `exportObject` (but 1 of the 3 is deprecated, so I listed the 2 above).